# Equivalent of Python's Map operator in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL DB like this.

```
ID, Name, scores.
10, abc,{23,19,34}
11, def, {2333,233,24}
12, ghi, {321,34}
13,hio,{}
```

scores in the above data model is an array or list of numbers.

Now we have to find all students who has any single score which is 19 when divided by 10. How can I achieve this?

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM students where 19 = ANY(scores)/10
```

Some thing like this works. But we need a better solution(using an inverted index probably) as the rows are in the order of millions.

```
SELECT * FROM students where 190 <= ANY(scores) < 200
```

Comment: what's the datatype of scores?

Comment: scores is a list of numbers.

Comment: What data type is the `scores` column in your db?

Comment: bigint[]  --- its an array of big integers

Answer (score 1):

In your data example there is no record that meet your condition of some value that when divided by 10 is =19. But i understand that you are sure about your condition that single number from array when divided by 10 should be equal to 19. Not sum of all or something?

First do you have gin index on score column?
Second - really single numbers in your score array will be bigger then int limit? If not bigint will just slow your queries.
Consider bigint issue and if you have to have it then, else remove ::bigint from query below

```
SELECT * FROM students where 
scores&&array[190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199]::bigint
```

It is ugly but probably faster then any tries of extract all number from array first then dividing them by 10 and then comparing to 19.
If you only search score for numbers that are equal 19 after dividing by 10, just use the method of Abelisto but it will be a killer during inserting as saving function index for milions of rows and long arrays will be slow.